# Refactoring: when visitor pattern can't be used to replace switch/instanceof

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring, visitor-pattern

I'm trying to do some refactoring on a piece of code using instanceof in order to determine the type. I think subtyping/polymorphism wouldnt work in this case (and even if it'd be too much of an overkill in this situation) and visitor pattern won't work here since I don't have the possibility to add an accept method to the annotation. Are there any other ways to make this sort of code cleaner/more readable?

```
for (Annotation annotation : method.getAnnotations()) {
            if (annotation instanceof DELETE) {
                setHttpMethod(annotation.annotationType().getSimpleName(), false);
                parsePath(((DELETE) annotation).value());
            } else if (annotation instanceof GET) {
                setHttpMethod(annotation.annotationType().getSimpleName(), false);
                parsePath(((GET) annotation).value());....
```

DELETE and GET look like this

```
public @interface DELETE {
  String value() default "";
}

public @interface GET {
  String value() default "";
}
```

An example for usage:

```
class Example {
      @DELETE("value") 
      Response method() {
...
      }
}
```

Comment: You could use reflection to call accept

Comment: Can you please show more details? I currently find it a bit hard to suggest anything without knowing your scenario in detail. What is `DELETE`, what is `GET`, are there annotations that should _not_ be considered, etc?

Comment: I don't understand annotations very well, but if `annotation instanceof DELETE` is true then `((DELETE) annotation)` is redundant upcasting. In which case the inside the `if` block is simply `setHttpMethod(annotation.annotationType().getSimpleName(), false);  parsePath(annotation.value());` in both cases. Does the body change ever?

Comment: @MiserableVariable no, that is downcasting. There is no value() method in Annotation. A String is an instance of Object. If you have a variable o of type Object, and have checked that `o instanceof String`, you can't do `o.substring()`. You need to do `((String) o).substring()`.

Comment: Oops :) I will delete my comment shortly

Comment: @JBNizet nevertheless, can't the OP declare a base annotation type with `value()` instance method that returns correct value for whatever the runtime type of the annotation may be? Still not visitor pattern, but the code simplifies to `if (annotation instanceof HttpVerb) { ...parsePath(((HttpVerb)annotation).value()); }`

Comment: @MiserableVariable If java would support annotation inheritance that might do it but this is not available in java

Comment: I should not speak about things I don't know well. On the other hand, I learned something. I think I was confused by Louis Wasserman's comment to JB Nizet's reply that "there are many annotations that are subtypes of DELETE which is may not be an annotation itself".

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE delete = method.getAnnotation(DELETE.class);
if (delete != null) {
    ...
}
GET get = method.getAnnotation(GET.class);
if (get != null) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Huh.  It looks to me like there are many annotations that are subtypes of `DELETE`, which is not necessarily an annotation itself.  I'm not sure this will work.

Comment: True, that might be the case. Although I doubt it: these annotations look like the standard JAX-RS annotations, and the OP uses the annotation name (DELETE, GET) as a HTTP method. So I doubt there actually is a SomeDeleteAnnotation class implementing DELETE, because there is no HTTP method called "SomeDeleteAnnotation". 
@user1769255: please clarify.

Comment: There are a number of annotations (1 per http method) but none is a subtype of another type.